# How to remove case sensitivity from Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

The aim for this program is for the user to enter a txt file name and find what is the most commonly used word and also how many times it has been used. The only issue is that words like "The" and "the" have different values because of case sensitivity. Is there a way to ignore it? Thanks

```
name = input("Enter the file name: ")
name = name + ".txt"
print(name)
handle = open(name,encoding="utf8")

counts = dict()
for line in handle:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1

bigcount = None
bigword = None
for word,count in counts.items():
    if bigcount is None or count > bigcount:
        bigword = word
        bigcount = count
print(bigword,bigcount)
```

Comment: is there a reason you don't just do words.lower() to make them all lowercase before you assess them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace this

```
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1
```

with

```
    for word in words:
        word = word.lower()
        counts[word] = counts.get(word,0) + 1
```

---

But all of the above except opening `handle` could be replaced with simply

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(w.lower() for l in handle for w in l.split())
print(counts.most_common(1))
```

Comment: I tried to use the .lower() before but I wrote it in the wrong line. Thank you very much it worked